# Future.get hangs when Callback catches InterruptedException

Tags: java

This code hangs. I understand that I call future.get() for the future that wasn't executed but I expect to see CancellationExcetpion or InterruptedException or some other exception on future.get() method. Am I wrong?

```
public class ExecutorTest {
    static ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<Future>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Future<Object> future = executorService.submit(new Callable<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object call() throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("Start task");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Finish task");
                    return "anything";
                }
            });
            futures.add(future);
        }

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    System.out.println("Shutdown Now");
                    executorService.shutdownNow();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Interrupted Exception during shutdown");
                }
            }
        }.start();

        for(Future f : futures) {
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
            System.out.println("before sleep");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("after sleep...");
            try {
                f.get();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("exception during future.get");
            }
            System.out.println("after get!");
        }

    }
}
```

This is my output

```
Start task
-------------------------
before sleep
after sleep...
Finish task
after get!
-------------------------
Start task
before sleep
after sleep...
Finish task
Start task
after get!
-------------------------
before sleep
after sleep...
Finish task
Start task
after get!
-------------------------
before sleep
Shutdown Now
Finish task
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at ru.pp.ExecutorTest$1.call(ExecutorTest.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
after sleep...
after get!
-------------------------
before sleep
after sleep...
```

Java 8, Intellij

If I replace

```
System.out.println("Start task");
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

with this

```
System.out.println("Start task");
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

then it doesn't hang

I'm frustrated...

Comment: What do you mean by _hang_? What should be executed after that?

Comment: By hang I mean that if I launch that code, it doesn't terminates and doesn't print 'after get!'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Thread_1 calls *FutureTask#get* then *Thread_1#wait* is called. Now to continue Thread_1 it should be notified by somebody. Notification is called ONLY when FutureTask is terminated (on *FutureTask#set*, *FutureTask#setException* or *FutureTask#cancel*). But in my case the FutureTask was never started because of shutdownNow (FutureTask was in state NEW). So it was never terminated and *Thread_1#notify* was never called. 
To fix it I got all not started futures from *#shutdownNow* and didn't call *FutureTask#get* for them.

PS: Honestly FutureTask uses sun.misc.Unsafe#park #unpark methods instead of wait and notify.

Answer (score 4):

When you invoke `shutdownNow`, the `ExecutorService` removes any scheduled, but not yet run, tasks and returns them to you as a `List<Runnable>`. These tasks have a corresponding `Future` which you already have a reference to. Since these tasks are never run, they never produce a result, ie. never complete. As such, the `Future#get()` for those tasks will never return.

If you wanted to, you could return run those tasks with

```
executorService.shutdownNow().forEach(r -> r.run());
```

and you would see your all `Future#get()` calls return.

You should probably only call `Future#get()` if you know the task is done/cancelled. Alternatively, give it a timeout.

Comment: Do you mean that it's absolutely wrong to call get() method for the future that was never executed? Why there is nothing about it in documentation and there is such exception as Cancellationexception? And it hangs only if I catch Interruptedexception.

Comment: @EugeneTo It doesn't only hang when you catch the exception. It hangs in all cases. The whole exception consequence was explained in @chiastic-security now deleted answer. That has nothing to do with why the program is hanging after `shutdownNow`. It's not wrong to call `get()`. You just shouldn't call it if you aren't sure if you'll get a result or not.

Comment: If you're using a standard ThreadPoolExecutor then the returned Runnables are the same Futures that were returned by submit (at least as of Java 7). If you cast them to Futures then you can invoke `Future#cancel(true)`. Then your later `get()` calls will throw a `CancellationException` as you would expect.